# How to store the .txt files in DocumnetDirectory

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdocumentdirectory

I am doing one application for iphone.In that i am creating .txt files and storing my information in that files.WHenever app open again i got the information from that files.Here is the code for creating the .txt files

```
     NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString* fileName = @"user_data.txt";
     NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
     }
```

And in some links i found if we save any data in DocumentDirectory then app will be reject by apple,because that data is upload to iCloud.So please tell me is it true or not.If yes then how can i store my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can't save any data before the app Launches for the first
>   time.i.e. If user user just install the app & not open the app then
>   Document Directory must be blank.
>
> If you launches the app then you can save data as much big as memory
>   is free in the device.
>
> If you store files in Documents, they will be backed up to iCloud
>   automatically.  If you don't want that, the easiest way is to just
>   store them somewhere else.  Library/Caches is a good choice.  If you
>   really MUST store in Documents but you want to disable iCloud backup
>   you can use the technique outlined here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Comment: I am creating the .txt files at run time only.So may be it's not a problem right?And from second time onwards data ia avaiable on direcctory.At app installation time it doesn't contain any data.

Comment: @venkat, then your app is not rejected by apple.

Comment: @venkat,Is this helpful to you?

Comment: Yes.It's very usefull.But y downvote for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html), You need to set "do not back up" attribute, or another solutions is that you can save files in /Library/Caches to avoid having it backed up.